# how to reference a range of bytes at an arbitrary position within VB.Net byte array

Tags: arrays, .net, vb.net

How can I refer to a range of elements beginning at a specific position within a Byte array?

I'm calling a function (see below) that receives chunks of bytes and I need to store each new chunk at the next position in the array (packet_buffer) after the prior chunk position (total_transferred_bytes_so_far ).

Obviously `packet_buffer( total_transferred_bytes_so_far )` doesn't work.

```
MOSI_count_bytes = BeagleApi.bg_spi_read_bit_timing(handle, status, _
                             time_sop, time_duration, _
                             time_dataoffset, _
                             remaining_to_read, packet_buffer( total_transferred_bytes_so_far ), _
                             remaining_to_read, data_miso, _
                             timing_size, timing)
```

Can't find anything on how to do this.

Comment: [`ArraySegment<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.arraysegment-1?view=netframework-4.8), or [`Span<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-3.1#spant-and-arrays) (if you are using core) can work, but your method would have to be built to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy elements from one array to another then call `Array.Copy`:

```vb
Array.Copy(sourceArray, 0, destinationArray, startIndex, sourceArray.Length)
```

That will copy every element from `sourceArray` into `destinationArray`, starting at `startIndex`.

Comment: Don’t want to copy. Want to, effectively, pass a reference (I E. A pointer) into a function.

Comment: How exactly do you receive a chunk of bytes not as an array that then has to be copied into another array?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an alternative to the valid answer by @jmcilhinney above:

```
Private Function GetRange(source As Byte(), start As Integer, length As Integer) As Byte()
    Return (From element In source Skip start Take length).ToArray
End Function
```